# Plot the surface $xy+z=1$, plane $x+y+z=1,$, and their curve of intersection in different colors

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, parametric-functions

Plot the surface $x y + z = 1$, plane $x+y+z=1$, and their curve of in intersection in different colors.

Answer (score 4):

Try [`ContourPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot3D.html) with the option [`BoundaryStyle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoundaryStyle.html):

```
ContourPlot3D[{x y + z == 1, x + y + z == 1}, 
 {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5},
 ContourStyle -> FaceForm[Opacity[.5]], 
 Mesh -> None, 
 BoundaryStyle -> 
   {{1} -> None, {2} -> None, {1, 2} ->  Directive[Green, Thick]}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

Comment: `{x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}` produces a somewhat  better plot.

Comment: Thank you @user64494. Updated with your suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_, y_] = SolveValues[x*y + z == 1, z][[1]]

(* 1 - x y *)

g[x_, y_] = SolveValues[x + y + z == 1, z][[1]]

(* 1 - x - y *)
```

Or using [`Mesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mesh.html) with [`Plot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot3D.html)

```
Plot3D[{f[x, y], g[x, y]}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5},
 PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.8],
 PlotLegends -> ({z==f[x, y], z==g[x, y]}),
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {x, y, z}),
 MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y}, f[x, y] - g[x, y]],
 Mesh -> {{0}},
 MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
myline = 
  ParametricPlot3D[{x, x/(x - 1), 1 - x - x/(x - 1)}, {x, -5, 5}, 
   PlotStyle -> Red];
Show[Plot3D[{1 - x y, 1 - x - y},
  {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}], myline]
```

Where you use:

```
Solve[1 - x y == 1 - x - y, y]
```

to find the intersection lines.

[image]

Comment: How do you derine `{x, x/(x - 1), 1 - x - x/(x - 1)}`?

Comment: Concerning your edit, `Solve[{1 - x y == 1 - x - y, x + y + z == 1}, {y, z}]` is a somewhat better way.

Answer (score 2):

Using [`ImplicitRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImplicitRegion.html) + [`DiscretizeRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscretizeRegion.html):

```
{surface1, surface2, intersection} = 
  Map[ImplicitRegion[#, {{x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}}] &] @ 
    {x y + z == 1,
     x + y + z == 1, 
     x y + z == 1 && x + y + z == 1};

Show[MapThread[
   DiscretizeRegion[#, MaxCellMeasure -> 10^-2, 
      BaseStyle -> Directive[#2, Thick, FaceForm[Opacity[.8]]]] &] @
   {{surface1, surface2, intersection}, 
    {ColorData[97] @ 2, ColorData[97] @ 1, Red}}, 
 Boxed -> True]
```

[image]